# JavaFX resizing webview problem on 2 monitors

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm new to javaFX and I'm using the webview. Everything works fine on my small monitor and I can see all the content of the webview. But when I drag my application to my bigger monitor (1920 x 1080) resolution. I can only see a part of the webview.
This is how the WebView looks like on my bigger monitor:

[image]

As you can see i can not see all the content of the webview on my bigger monitor. 
I than tried resizing the webview like this so I can see all the content on my bigger monitor:

```
double height = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();
        double width = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        //Create WebView
        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.setMinWidth(width);
        view.setMinHeight(height);
```

The problem now is that the webview height and width is to big for my smaller screen.

I'm displaying my webview in a tab of a tabpane like this:

```
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);
tab1.setContent(view);
```

How can I make it so that the webview size will adjust to the current screen the stage currently is?
Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I see a ScollPane to the right. I am guessing that the HTML height needs to be set to a higher value, or the JavaFX node height needs to be set to a higher value. I am leaning toward the first one.

Comment: How can I set the height of the HTML to a higher value?

Comment: I just went to test.com. The issue was not as bad on my machine. I think the problem here could be the technology behind the site. Try http://www.google.com to see if you continue to have this problem.

Comment: It's the same on every website I visit within the webview. The problem is not the website, the problem is the webview having the width and length of my smaller monitor but not my bigger monitor, so when i open the app in my bigger monitor i can only see a part of the webview

Comment: I have a 24 in monitor  and I am having no problems on Google's site.

Comment: I don´t think you understand the problem. The problem only occurs when I have 2 monitors connected at the same time. When I drag my JavaFX application to my bigger monitor the WebView does not expand

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I **highly** recommend you to work with SceneBuilder (Drag & Drop user interface design): https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

SceneBuilder stores the view in a FXML file, and you can use it as follows:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I also recommend you to work with IntelliJ: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html

If you do so, you can set the value of pref width/height property to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE over the SceneBuilder GUI, that would solve your problem.

Another (ugly) solution without SceneBuilder would be:

```
setMinWidth(getWidth());
setMinHeight(getHeight());
```

Comment: Hey thanks I'll keep that in mind and use SceneBuilder for my next project. For the ugly solution, on what property do i need to set the min width and height? I tried doing this: view.setMinWidth(getWidth());
        view.setMinHeight(getHeight()); But it can't find getWidth() and getHeight().

Comment: Try root.setMaxHeight(root.getMaxHeight());

Comment: I didn't have a property called root, but I just created a stackpane called root, put the webview in it and did : root.setMaxHeight(root.getMaxHeight()); root.setMaxWidth(root.getMaxWidth()); and it did not work